# How can I, in one command, create or update a remote?

Tags: git, github, deployment, git-branch

I don't know whether a remote called `origin` already exists. The command

```
git remote add origin gti@gtihub......git
```

throws the error

```
fatal: remote origin already exists
```

I need to add an `origin` remote if it does not exists, and update it if it already exists. How can I do that in one command?

(For information, I use Git version 1.7.3.4.)

Also, what is the difference between:

- `git remote add origin gti@gtihub......git`
- `git remote set-url origin gti@gtihub......git`
- `git remote set-url --add origin gti@gtihub......git`

Does any one of those commands do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] what is the difference between [...]

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

adds a remote named `<name>` for the repository at `<url>`.

```
git remote set-url <name> <url>
```

sets the URL for the remote called `<name>` to `<url>`.

```
git remote set-url --add <name> <url>
```

adds a new (push) URL for the remote called `<name>`; that's probably not what you want to do.

The first command throws an error if a remote called `<name>` already exists, whereas the last two commands throw an error if no remote called `<name>` exist.

Refer to the [`git-remote` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) for more details.

> I need to add remote origin when it does not exists, and update it if it already exists.

You can use conditional execution for that:

```
git remote add <name> <url> >/dev/null 2>&1 || git remote set-url <name> <url>
```

The second command (`git remote set-url ...`) will only be run if the first one (`git remote add ...`) returns with a nonzero exit code.

The `>/dev/null 2>&1` part is for redirecting the standart output and standard error of the first command to `/dev/null`, which you can think of as UNIX's "bottomless pit"; [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-redirect-output-and-errors-to-devnull/) is an introduction to output redirection.

For convenience, you may want to define an alias for this.

Comment: what does mean "/dev/null" in last command? and actually "2>&1" ?